# Clustering with ranking data

Tags: clustering, ranking, ranks

I'm just trying to get some practice with implementing some Machine Learning algorithms with a variety of data. I'm just getting started so I'm pretty new to the whole process and would appreciate any guidance in this task.

I've happened across a nice dataset of around 200 people who ranked the 9 main Star Wars titles from 1-9 in their order of preference. I was wondering if it would be sensible to try to cluster folk into groupings based on this data. I think I'm curious to see if there people whose preferences lead them to rank certain movies in the franchise closer together.

From my studies, I figure that a clustering algorithm might be the approach here. I've learned about K-means so far which seems to be appropriate for market segmentation problems which this seems vaguely analogous to. Do you think this is an appropriate approach for this problem? I'm also very open to learning about different approaches. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have voted to close the Q as having a duplicate already. I also have moved my answer from here to that older thread.